# How to show worklog in a weekly breakdown on a JIRA dashboard gadget?

Tags: jira, dashboard, administration

For total worklog I use a Counter gadget summing time spent (and a simple filter specifying project, issuetype and labels (customfield).

Please advise, what filter and gadget should I use to see total worklog in a weekly breakdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Sprint Burndown gadget.